# Winform application not running after installing into program files directory

Tags: c#, winforms

I had created a windows form application and used setup project to create installer. But after installing my application the application is not opening from the location it is installed("c:\Programs Files(86x)\"). But the application runs fine if i copy the entire installed files to another drive. Actually my application is creating some folder inside the installed directory when running. so i thought it is some problem related to windows permissions. I had set app privileges as "requireAdministrator" and still not working. Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: Surely the comprehensive error handling and logging within your application gives you sufficient information? Failing that, when you attached the debugger to your application what did it say?

Comment: *"Actually my application is creating some folder inside the installed directory when running."* That is your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually my application is creating some folder inside the installed directory when running.

**Don't do that!**

The Program Files folder is *read only* to standard users, and has been since Windows 2000. And since Windows Vista even Administrator users will require elevation to get write access into this folder.

Use the All Users Application Data folder instead (`Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`).

The alternative is an advanced installer product (meaning purchasing the full version of InstallShield or similar rather than the version included with Visual Studio) which supports adding an *action* to your install process that both creates the folder and sets new permissions, and does this at install time. But that's really a cheat, anyway. Just use Application Data.